# update color in runtime in winapi window using gdi

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I'm trying to show the color user enters in a special rectangle inside my ui window.
So far I'm able to read out user color input, but somehow the color of the rectangle I draw is not changed.
I try to use InvalidateRect(wnd, NULL, TRUE) to cause window repaint, but it doesn't work.

It seems I don't understand something elementary about winapi runtime functioning. Here is my code with comments:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

void createEditProc(HWND);

HWND hColorInput;
WNDPROC ColorEditProc;

struct color {
    float r;
    float g;
    float b;
};
color current_color = { 1, 0.5, 1 };


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE PrevInst, LPSTR args, int ncmdshow) {
    WNDCLASSW wc = { 0 };
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"myWindowClass";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;

    if (!RegisterClassW(&wc))
        return -1;

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(L"myWindowClass", L"My Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        100, 100, 570, 330, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    MSG msg = { 0 };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);

    }
    

    return 0;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        createEditProc(hWnd);
        break;

    case WM_PAINT:
        {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        HBRUSH newBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(floor(current_color.r * 255), floor(current_color.g * 255), floor(current_color.b * 255)));
        HGDIOBJ oldBrush = SelectObject(hdc, newBrush);
        Rectangle(hdc, 10,  10, 200, 200);
        SelectObject(hdc, oldBrush);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);
    }
}


std::string read_textInput(HWND hEdit) {
    wchar_t colorcode0[1000];
    GetWindowTextW(hEdit, colorcode0, 1000);
    std::wstring ws(colorcode0);
    std::string colorcode(ws.begin(), ws.end());
    return colorcode;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK subEditProc(HWND wnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case VK_RETURN:
        {
            std::string color_text = read_textInput(hColorInput);
            char* cstr = new char[color_text.length() + 1];
            strcpy_s(cstr, color_text.length() + 1, color_text.c_str());
            int r, g, b;
            sscanf_s(cstr, "%02x%02x%02x", &r, &g, &b);
            current_color.r = r / 255.;
            current_color.g = g / 255.;
            current_color.b = b / 255.;
            InvalidateRect(wnd, NULL, TRUE); // is it correct? 
        }
        break;  //or return 0; if you don't want to pass it further to def proc. If not your key, skip to default:
        }
    default:
        return CallWindowProc(ColorEditProc, wnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}


void createEditProc(HWND hWnd)
{
    hColorInput = CreateWindowW(L"EDIT", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL, 465, 30, 65, 25, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    ColorEditProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(hColorInput, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)subEditProc);
}
```

Function `subEditProc` reads user input hex color code after the user hits enter and puts it into current_color struct.

In my `WM_PAINT` function the `Rectangle` is drawn with `newBrush` with this color. Somehow, despite the fact that my current_color indeed changes correctly when the user hits `enter`, it never updates in the newBrush.

As far as I understand I should add somewhere the redraw functionality. May be with the help of redrawwindow function. But strangely enough, I never encountered working example with this function.

In despretation I added `InvalidateRect(wnd, NULL, TRUE)` in my handling of message `WM_KEYDOWN`. But I don't think this is correct. Also, when I change the size of the window and message `WM_PAINT` is called, it doens't change the color.

Comment: First parameter of `InvalidateRect` should be handle of the window to be repainted while you pass edit window handle.

Comment: Also, you are leaking a brush object for every execution of the `WM_PAINT` handler. Either call `DeleteObject` when you're done using the brush, or use `GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH)` and `SetDCBrushColor` instead of creating a solid brush object.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I corrected the lickage. About the correct handle in InvalidateRect... I thought that it got ```wnd``` handle. This ```wnd``` handle is then participates in createEditProc function which is taken with ```hWnd``` handle (the hanlde of the main window)?

Comment: The `wnd` passed into the custom window procedure of the subclassed control is unrelated to the `hWnd` passed into the regular window procedure. You're going to have to get the edit control's parent window's handle, one way or another. Far easier, though, don't even subclass the edit control, and handle [EN_CHANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/en-change) notifications in the parent window.

Comment: I followed your first advice and it worked! Very much appericated. I post an aswer with an updated working code.

Answer (score 1):

Just understood my error and Here I post the working example for people who will need that kind of functionality:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

void createEditProc(HWND);

HWND hColorInput, hWnd, hMainWindow;
WNDPROC ColorEditProc;

struct color {
    float r;
    float g;
    float b;
};
color current_color = { 1, 0.5, 1 }; // We set initial color of the window.

// Here is the main window. Here I define the handle hMainWindow to repaint it later.

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE PrevInst, LPSTR args, int ncmdshow) {
    WNDCLASSW wc = { 0 };
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"myWindowClass";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;

    if (!RegisterClassW(&wc))
        return -1;

    hMainWindow = CreateWindowW(L"myWindowClass", L"My Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        100, 100, 570, 330, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    MSG msg = { 0 };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);

    }
    

    return 0;
}


// WinMain call back function

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        createEditProc(hWnd);
        break;

    case WM_PAINT:
        {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        HBRUSH newBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(floor(current_color.r * 255), floor(current_color.g * 255), floor(current_color.b * 255)));
        HGDIOBJ oldBrush = SelectObject(hdc, newBrush);
        Rectangle(hdc, 10,  10, 200, 200);
        SelectObject(hdc, oldBrush);
        DeleteObject(newBrush);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);
    }
}


std::string read_textInput(HWND hEdit) {
    wchar_t colorcode0[1000];
    GetWindowTextW(hEdit, colorcode0, 1000);
    std::wstring ws(colorcode0);
    std::string colorcode(ws.begin(), ws.end());
    return colorcode;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK subEditProc(HWND wnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case VK_RETURN:
        {
            std::string color_text = read_textInput(hColorInput);
            char* cstr = new char[color_text.length() + 1];
            strcpy_s(cstr, color_text.length() + 1, color_text.c_str());
            int r, g, b;
            sscanf_s(cstr, "%02x%02x%02x", &r, &g, &b);
            current_color.r = r / 255.;
            current_color.g = g / 255.;
            current_color.b = b / 255.;
            InvalidateRect(hMainWindow, NULL, TRUE); // here I pass hMainWindow handle causing it to repaint.
        }
        break; 
        }
    default:
        return CallWindowProc(ColorEditProc, wnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}


void createEditProc(HWND hWnd)
{
    hColorInput = CreateWindowW(L"EDIT", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL, 465, 30, 65, 25, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    ColorEditProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(hColorInput, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)subEditProc);
}
```